# Abstract class contained within concrete class

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, abstract-class

I have a class which contains, as a member, another class.  The second class is an abstract class being made concrete by one of a range of daughter classes in the usual way.
I am unsure about the best way to go about constructing the all-encompasing class as, surely, when it it is constructed errors will be thrown since it will try to construct a class which is missing a definition for some of its methods.  Could anyone advise about the best way to get around this?
Cheers,
Jack

Edit 1: Class diagram:

```
                 Main Class
                      |
       ------------------------------------
       |                                  |
Normal Methods/Members             Abstract Class member
                                          |
                            -----------------------------
                            |                           |
                     Concrete Class 1           Concrete Class 2
```

So 'Main Class' is the construction I'm worried about as when it is called, the abstract class member needs be made concrete somehow but I'm not sure how best to do it.

Comment: Can you post your code to make your question more clear?

Comment: I can't post the code as it's a pretty bulky.  I can try to draw a little class structure diagram though

Comment: you can at least post your classes structure...

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without some (simplified) sample code that reproduces your actual error. However the phrase "all-encompasing class" sounds like a bad design. Objects should be implemented for exactly one responsibility.

Comment: if the `Main Class` has a member of `Abstract Class` you can't instantiate it, as the `Main Class` is now abstract as well. in the above scenario you can create only `Concrete Class 1` or `Concrete Class 2`

Comment: Is that an inheritance diagram, or an encapsulation diagram? Or a weird mix of both? Please show some example code (it doesn't have to be actual code, just something that show us what you are doing or what you want).

Comment: OK, so before when I was working with just the 'Abstract class' by itself I would just call the constructor of the concrete class.  But what is the right thing to do here, since I dont want *just* a concrete version of the abstract class, I want the 'Main' class with one of a number of the concrete classes?

Answer (score 1):

Given an abstract class `A` and two implementations `B`,`C` and `enc` that should encompass them, I can think of two solutions:

The first having a `unique_ptr` of `A`, `enc` would look like:

```
struct enc{
    unique_ptr<A> a;
    int x;
    enc(unique_ptr<A> p): a(std::move(p)), x(0) {
    }       
};
```

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/rZ7TQj).

And the second solution which I happened to think of and I'm not sure is a great idea but I'll post for the sake of versatility (and or finding out whether it has flaws that I didn't think of). Using templates in case `A`, `B` are some default constructable classes

```
template <class T>
struct enc{
    T in; // should be private, I'm just lazy :)
    A &a; 
    int x;
    enc(): in(T()), a(in), x(0) {
    }       
};
```

(Assuming op requires some sort of pointer or reference to parent class in `enc`)

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/Te5dIG).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand exactly what you mean, but it seems to me that you could use a pointer or a reference to the abstract class, and then initialize it with a concrete class.

Something like

```
class MainClass
{
    class AbstractClass
    {
    public:
        virtual void SomeFunction() = 0;
        ...
    };

    class ConcreteClass : public AbstractClass
    {
    public:
        ConcreteClass() {}
        void SomeFunction() { ... }
        ...
    };

    AbstractClass* pAbstractClass;

public:
    MainClass()
        : pAbstractClass(new ConcreteClass)
    {}

    virtual ~MainClass()
    {
        delete pAbstractPointer;
    }

    ...

    void AnotherFunction()
    {
        pAbstractClass->SomeFunction();
    }
};
```

Just create an instance of any concrete class inheriting from the abstract base class, and assign to the pointer to the abstract class.

Comment: I think you should warn about having to call `delete pAbstractClass` in `MainClass`'s destructor, in case one uses raw pointers :)

Comment: @Scis I upvoted your answer just because of your use of smart pointers. :)